# Add link to LinkedIn profile in new Developer Story profile

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I've seen that in the new developer story profile page there are options to add :

- Personal website
- Twitter profile
- Github profile

Why LinkedIn profile is missing here ? 
It would be nice to have .

Comment: Even on SO regular profile LinkedIn inst supported. I doubt on Developers story.